# Using one search form to search multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working a simple rails app and i would like to know how possible it is to use one search form to search inside multiple models. like i have a story model and a book model. this search form should be able to search the both models with a single parameter.

`<%= for_tag :url => search_path %>
 <%= text_field_tag :q %>
<% end %>`

How can i make this search from work for multipple models

Answer (score 0):

Whatever search you need to do, is done inside an action in a controller. You could basically create a controller, say **search_controller** and have an action say, **item**

```
def item

   if params[:q]
       @found_stories = Story.find_all_by_...(params[:q])
       @found_books= Book.find_all_by_...(params[:q])
   end

end
```

Then you could use the objects @found_stories and @found_books in your view to show the search results.

This is just an example of how you could do to fulfill your requirement.

Thanks.